# No communication between Server Channel Java NIO

Tags: java, server, client, nio

I am learning about the java.nio library and I read [this](http://www.baeldung.com/java-nio-selector) article on using a `Selector` instead of using multiple threads. I am trying to send a simple string from the client to the server. When I run both programs no string is sent.

Client:

```
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(message.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    try {
        client.write(buffer);
        buffer.clear();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where `client` & `buffer` are:

```
client = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", portNumber));
buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2000);
```

Server:

```
final int PORT = 18888;
Selector selector;
ServerSocketChannel serverSocket;
ByteBuffer buffer;
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
try{
    selector = Selector.open();
    serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", PORT));
    serverSocket.configureBlocking(false);
    serverSocket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2000);
    ChatProtocol chat = new ChatProtocol();

    while(true){
        selector.select();
        Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator iter = selectedKeys.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            SelectionKey key =  (SelectionKey)iter.next();

            if(key.isAcceptable()){
                SocketChannel client = serverSocket.accept();
                client.configureBlocking(false);
                client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            }

            if(key.isReadable()){
                SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
                System.out.println("Read Started");
                client.read(buffer);
                System.out.println(charset.decode(buffer).toString());
                //chat.ProccessInput(charset.decode(buffer).toString());
                buffer.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

P.S It should be also noted that when i close my client side, the message "Read Started" appears in console

Comment: You're ignoring end of stream. If `read()` returns -1 you must close the channel. You must also clear the selected key set every time around the loop.

Comment: @EJP Thank you! I seem to have missed the 'iter.remove()' shown in the example. I will look into how to close the channel as well.

Comment: @EJP I make the changes, and I am still getting the same issue. I posted it [here](https://pastebin.com/5VJ9wB0Z). Is there anything else you can see?

Comment: `client.close()` followed by a printout of the unchanged buffer is pretty pointless, don't you think? You need an `else` after the `close` block.